# Re-writing Page name

Tags: url, redirect

Link#1  "medical.html" we change that page to
Link#2  "medical-transcription.html"

I want the person who clicked Link#1 to go to Link#2, not our home page.  It is transparent to the end user because they find the information they want and it allows us to pass along (and keep) our search engine rankings.

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: i am using IIS 7.0 as it have URL redirection is working fine http://outsourcestrategies.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to setup either a 301 or 302 redirect within IIS, there is a [good article on IIS redirection](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-http-redirection/2008-03-27/) you can refer to.

Comment: Thx for the Reply, but redirection is working fine in .htaccess i am asking is there any possibilities to rename "medical.html" to "medical-transcription.html" people come and clicks on the link medical.html but he see the url is medical-transcription.html. Issue is both are same extinction. if any info pls Help i need urgent :)

Comment: Arun, I must not be understanding what you are asking. If you setup a redirect for http://servername/medical.html to http://servername/medical-transcription.html then it should seamlessly move a user to the 2nd url when they click on the first (and the same for search links, etc.)